# How to secure communication between Pact Broker, Consumer and Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, authentication, pact, pact-broker

We are planning to implement CDC in our project and Pact is being considered as primary candidate. Currently I am working on a POC to set up end to end flow with CI/CD integration with GitLab. I have couple of questions related to Authentication/Authorization/security.

1. Consumer - Pact Broker: Consumers here are external partners.  I see client side certificates as an option. I am not able to find much documentation or info on Web for the options available. Pact broker will be hosted in AWS. Can we place this behind a gateway?
2. Pact Broker and Provider: Both components are part of our infrastructure. In this case I understand that we will be generating a GitLab trigger token which will be passed as part of future requests to Provider pipeline. We will be using same token every time.

Could you please advise options available in both cases to make the communication more secure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> We are planning to implement CDC in our project and Pact is being considered as primary candidate.

Good choice! :)

> I have couple of questions related to Authentication/Authorization/security

The OSS broker doesn’t have any security controls other than basic auth and read-only/read-write access permissions (which isn’t very appropriate for external use for obvious reasons). There is basic support for redacting credentials in the UI, but you can still get them through API calls (even for read-only accounts).

> Consumer - Pact Broker: Consumers here are external partners. I see client side certificates as an option. I am not able to find much documentation or info on Web for the options available. Pact broker will be hosted in AWS. Can we place this behind a gateway?

Where did you see that client certificates were supported? I’m sorry to say that is incorrect.

You can definitely put it behind a gateway/reverse proxy type thing: https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/configuration/#running-the-broker-behind-a-reverse-proxy

You would need to add your own authentication layer for this purpose, so using a an API gateway for this that might be a good starting point.

> Pact Broker and Provider: Both components are part of our infrastructure. In this case I understand that we will be generating a GitLab trigger token which will be passed as part of future requests to Provider pipeline. We will be using same token every time.

The provider side authentication is the same as consumer.

Alternatively, we have created Pactflow, which is a commercial version of the OSS Broker designed for enterprise use which has a full security model wrapped over the OSS broker including API tokens, and secrets, teams management and other useful features (see https://pactflow.io/features/ for more). We are also almost ready [release](https://github.com/pactflow/roadmap/projects/1) CI users and fine-grained permissions management.